# python pretty print parse_and_eval

Tags: python, gdb

Does anyone know how to tell if a given variable is valid when its pretty printer is invoked from gdb.

For example one of my pretty printers uses gdb.parse_and_eval which causes gdb to crash unless the variable has been initialised.

```
TestPrettyPrint::TestPrettyPrint(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QFile f("C:/Log.txt");
}
```

If i put a break point on the first line and try to examine 'f' gdb crashes. If I put a break point after when 'f' has been created everything is fine.

Any information would be extremely helpful

Thanks

Comment: gdb shouldn't crash; if it does, it's a bug. At worst, it should raise an exception showing that there was an error in the evaluation, which you should then catch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell whether or not a variable is valid.

First, this information is not available in the debug information.  To be precise, there is a GCC extension to DWARF to provide this information, however it was not well-specified and doesn't really work; and in any case it isn't exposed to Python in GDB.

Second, even if the information were available, it would not solve the problem.  Any memory can be trashed by a bug.

The answer is for pretty-printers to be adaptable.  You can use existing "print" settings to limit the amount of garbage that is emitted.

If gdb crashes, then that is a gdb bug which should be reported.  I know there is something like this in bugzilla already, though IIRC it does not have reproduction instructions.  That is the most vital thing in order for the bug to be fixed.